# Google Cloud SQL Postgres Vs Self Hosted Postgres using GCP Compute instances: HIPAA Compliance

Tags: postgresql, security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, hipaa

This question is about infosec, data privacy, specifically HIPAA compliance on GCP.

Is there any advantages for self managing Postgres server (built on GCP Compute instances using lets say Terraform) my own Vs using the managed offering, i,e. Cloud SQL

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Google Cloud SQL Postgres` is a fully managed option for deploying PostgreSQL to Google Cloud. The fully managed option is convenient, but is mainly suitable for cloud-native applications, or applications rebuilt for the cloud.

It has Built-in encryption for database tables, temporary files, backups, and any data transferred over Google’s internal networksSecure connections via SSL/TLS or the `Cloud SQL Proxy`.

#### Update1

As you are referring to HIPAA You can check this guide for [HIPAA Compliance on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa)  Cloud sql [encrypts the data at rest](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#encryption-manage-rest:%7E:text=Auth%20proxy.-,How%20is%20encryption%20managed%20for%20data%20at%20rest%3F,-Your%20data%20is) using the 256-bit Advanced Encryption Standard (AES-256), or better, with symmetric keys: that is, the same key is used to encrypt the data when it is stored, and to decrypt it when it is used. You can use your own encryptions as well with [CMEK for cloud sql](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-cmek)

And also you mentioned Infosec. I have not completely understood the term. I assume that you are referring to securing information from vulnerabilities. You can use [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/cloud-armor-overview),  which is a network security service that provides defenses against DDoS and application attacks like cross-site scripting (XSS) and SQL injection (SQLi).

Self hosted `Postgres` gives you full control over your `PostgreSQL` database on GCP, letting you to fine-tune server parameters, modify database configuration, and tune performance, just like in a local deployment.

#### Update2

As per this [thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/81632DEC-4DDE-49CD-A421-0E2C5A9E222E@holmusk.com#:%7E:text=Postgres%20engine%20is%20*not*%20HIPAA%20compliant:%7E:text=Postgres%20engine%20is%20*not*%20HIPAA%20compliant), it seems like `postgresql` is not HIPAA compliant.

For Encryption at rest on `postgresql` use can `PostgreSQL TDE` and `Pgcrypto` as discussed in this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61200974/18265570)

For self hosted postgres You can also use [shielded VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/shielded-vm) using which you can protect enterprise workloads from threats like remote attacks, privilege escalation, and malicious insiders

**I am not sure on your application requirement, But based upon my
understanding about both `cloud sql` and `self hosted postgres` I
would recommend considering cloud sql as the best option as it is
fully managed by google and also complies with HIPAA and encryption.**

For more information about pros and cons of `Google Cloud SQL Postgres` and Self hosted `Postgres`, Check this [document](https://bluexp.netapp.com/blog/gcp-cvo-blg-google-cloud-postgresql-managed-or-self-managed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking only for the Infosec, encryption at rest, HIPAA compliance aspect of it

Comment: @so-random-dude I have updated my answer. Can you have a look at it once?

Comment: upvoted for your effort. However I couldn't see any place where it stated postgresSQL is not HIPAA compliant

Comment: This [line](https://i.paste.pics/KT8YC.png) in the [link](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/81632DEC-4DDE-49CD-A421-0E2C5A9E222E@holmusk.com#:%7E:text=Postgres%20engine%20is%20*not*%20HIPAA%20compliant:%7E:text=Postgres%20engine%20is%20*not*%20HIPAA%20compliant) made me think that postgres is not HIPAA complaint, I couldn't find any supporting document explaining it. I apologize that I couldn't cover all the information. And thanks for your suggestions

Comment: It's how you use and setup the tech, not the tech you use. You can likely make an excel spreadsheet on a portable drive HIPAA compliant if you implement the proper controls(data access logs, encryption at rest, in transit, lock it in a secure cage with a camera recording access etc).

Comment: It seems google cloud lists cloud sql as covered to be HIPAA compliant  That service can run Postgres.  You still as the developer need to implement a bunch of stuff in your solution to make your solution compliant. Google is just saying their infra has the safeguards in place that make it HIPAA compliant to use your stuff on it.  The user of the system you build has to use the said system in a HIPAA-compliant manner. It's a multi-layered onion. https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa#covered-products